# How can I log a user out of Facebook programmatically?

Tags: facebook, terminal, share

I am doing a website for a public terminal where the users are able to share a picture on facebook, but once a user logged in for sharing, the next user will go directly to the sharing of the first user.

Is ist possible to start sharer.php with a new user or log the first automatically out?

Comment: Can you post some source snippet of your attempt?

Comment: Not possible to first force a logout on Facebook. You could perhaps use JS to open the logout URL and then open the sharer.php URL in that same window.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use `FB.logout` from the JS-SDK. When you call that, FB will log out the currently active user.

The documentation is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/).